# Help with finding the Lebesgue decomposition of measures

Tags: real-analysis, measure-theory, lebesgue-measure, radon-nikodym

Consider the increasing, right-continuous function
$$ F(x) = 
\begin{cases} 0      &x < 0 \\
              1+x    &x \geq 0
\end{cases}
$$

and let $\nu = \nu_F$ be the associated Borel measure on $\mathbb R$ (so $\nu((a,b]) = F(b)-F(a)$).  Find the Lebesgue decomposition of $\nu$ with respect to:

(a) $m$

(b) $\delta$, the Dirac measure at 0

(c) the Cantor measure $\mu$

I think I have a solution to (a), but I am lost as to how to do parts (b) and (c). I'd appreciate any help.

This is my attempt for (a):

We want to find measures $\rho$ and $\lambda$ such that
$$\nu = \rho + \lambda$$
with $\rho << m$ and $\lambda \perp m$. By the Radon-Nikodym Theorem, $\exists F'$ such that
$$\rho(A) = \int_A F'(x) dx. $$

Since $F(x)$ is increasing then for some interval $(a,b] \in \mathcal B$,
$$\rho((a,b]) = \int_a^b F'(x) dx \leq F(b)-F(a) = \nu((a,b]). $$

Clearly, $\rho << m $. Next define $$\lambda = \nu-\rho.$$
To show that $\lambda \perp m$, let $E = \{0\}$ and $F = \mathbb R - \{0\}.$ We want to show that $m(E)=\lambda(F)=0$. It is trivial that $m(E) = 0$. To show $\lambda(F) =0$, notice $\lambda \geq 0$ since $\rho(A) \leq \nu(A) \ \ \forall A \in \mathcal B.$ Hence on $(-\infty,0):$
$$ \lambda((-\infty,0))=\nu(-\infty,0)-\rho(-\infty,0)\geq 0  $$
But since $\nu(-\infty,0)=0$, then $\rho((-\infty,0)=0 \implies \lambda((-\infty,0) = 0$. Finally on $(0, \infty),$ note that $\nu = \rho$. Hence
$$ \lambda((0,\infty)) = \nu((0,\infty))-\rho((0,\infty))=0$$

Comment: I think your decomposition of (a) is wrong since $\nu_F(\{0\})=1$. I would say that I think the decomposition is probably $\nu_F=m+\delta_0$.

Comment: For (c), if you show that the cantor measure and $\nu_F$ are singular , then the solution is simple.

Comment: @keen-ameteur You're right. Thanks. Quick question if you don't mind. If F was instead $3+x$ when $x \geq 0$ and 0 otherwise would the decomposition be $m+3\delta_0$?